# Using GCP from an iPad Pro

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, nano

Using GCP from an iPad Pro : I access to my VM through SSH, and then edit a file with NANO, but cannot use intro key after Ctrl-O to save a file, where I could find find help to ses iPad keyboard in a NANO session?
Thanks!

I have already tried with any combination of CAP; command, option, control + key